# spring restfull webservice post method

Tags: spring, rest, post

Thanks for your time.

I have written spring restfull webservice to handle the post method in my spring controller class, while i am testing with SOAP UI and RestClient i am getting "415 post method not available" message.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insertperfinfo)
public class SessionInfoController implements Controller {
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) 
   public ModelAndView insertPerfinfoGet(HttpServletRequest request,Model model){
     String user=request.getParameter("user");
   }

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) 
   public ModelAndView insertPerfinfoPOST(@RequestBody Perf perf,Model model) {
     // control not comes here .. when i give post request via REST client
   }

}
```

FYI :
     Working

```
  1.url is : http://server.port/webapp/insertperf?user=java&status=enable
  1.1.for GET method it is working fine as i expected .

Not working :
  2.i have created the Perf POJO in my web layer for query string parameter.
  2.2 passing the parameter via RESTClient with POST method.
  2.3 415 post method not available message
```

Any advise? thanks in advance.

Regards
Vasanth D

Comment: Please provide the details for your requests. Also, how is your DispatchServlet mapped in web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the return type of your POST method to `Perf`. Also, annotate it with `@ResponseBody`. Finally, I see no need for the `Model`. So like this:

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) 
   @ResponseBody
   public Perf insertPerfinfoPOST(@RequestBody Perf perf) {
     ...
   }
```

Comment: I have tried the above solutions which is given by user1257931 and vidya...both are not working..i am getting below error message

Comment: Make sure you have a JSON serializer/deserializer like Jackson in the classpath and `mvc:annotation-driven` in your Spring configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is a missing quote at the end of your annotation for the Class.

Also, try removing the RequestMapping annotation from the Class definition and modify the ReqeustMapping annotations of the methods:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET,value = "/insertperfinfo")

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST,value = "/insertperfinfo")
```

Comment: Thanks for your input , i will try it, one more query : do i need any parameter to handle the JSON string in my controller ?

Comment: Any  one can you please help on this?

Comment: Can you post the spring log4j debug output to a pastebin?